# MySQL - Optimizing the select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I have got about 4.4K records in `stockmain` table and 4.4K records in `stockdetail` table and bout 1.04K records in `item` table. I have got the following query:

```
SELECT 
    item.model, 
    stockdetail.docs, 
    item.category, 
    stockdetail.item_id, 
    stockdetail.chasis, 
    stockdetail.price, 
    stockdetail.tax, 
    stockdetail.recycle, 
    stockdetail.auction, 
    stockdetail.shaken, 
    stockdetail.transport, 
    stockdetail.fee, 
    stockdetail.netamount, 
    IFNULL(SUM(QTY),0) as QTY, 
    item.DESCRIPTION 
FROM 
    stockmain 
        INNER JOIN stockdetail 
            ON stockmain.STID=stockdetail.STID 
        INNER JOIN item 
            ON stockdetail.ITEM_ID = item.ITEM_ID 
WHERE 
    stockmain.vrdate 
        BETWEEN '{$startDate}' AND '{$endDate}'
AND stockmain.company_id={$company_id} 
GROUP BY 
    item.item_id, chasis HAVING IFNULL(SUM(QTY),0) > 0 ORDER BY item.description, item.model
```

and it takes average number of about 45-48 seconds to load the data. How may I optimize this query to perform faster?

P.S I have tried by adding the indexes to `stockmain`.`vrdate` and `stockmain`.`company_id` but that changed nothing.

Below is the `EXPLAIN` for the above query`

```
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len |      ref                    | rows  | Extra                            |
| 1  |   SIMPLE    | stockdetail | ALL    |               |          |         |                             |  4180 |  Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1  |   SIMPLE    | item        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       |  PRIMARY | 4       | kashmir.stockdetail.item_id |  1    |                                  |
| 1  |   SIMPLE    | stockmain   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       |  PRIMARY | 4       | kashmir.stockdetail.stid    |  1    |  Using where                     |
```

Comment: Please post the explain plan for the query

Comment: You need to index on columns `ITEM_ID` and `STID` from `stockdetail` table also use `HAVING QTY > 0` rather using whole expression

Comment: How long does it take without the HAVING part ? Also maybe you could try using another alias for the quantity column and using it in the having instead, maybe SQL is calculating the field twice instead of once ?